# Make a plot using one column as start and another as stop for boxes

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a .bed file that details where specific genes are in a genome and I'd like to plot boxes depicting these genes over an x axis depicting the chromosomes they're on. While there seem to be a lot of tools for doing this in various ways, they all look pretty ugly so if possible i'd like to do it with ggplot where I have more control over the final product's look. The file is formatted in four columns as:

```
chromosomeNAME geneStart geneEnd geneName ChrmLength
         chrm1   3714014 3735354    geneA    6509629
         chrm1   4130851 4178170    geneB    6509629
         chrm2    264426  307752    geneC    5196352
         chrm2    334381  382612    geneD    5196352
```

So i'd like the above to put out two x axis one for chromosome one and one for chromosome two that go from 1-chrmlength and then have boxes above the axis that are filled in from geneStart to geneEnd. Ideally these boxes would be color coded in a legend.

I know how to facet the graph but I'm not sure how to get ggplot to output a filled-in box using the start/end coordinates as depicted above.

thanks!

Comment: `geom_segment` or `geom_rect`? Not sure exactly what you're after—maybe you can find an example of what this should look like

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

[image]

If that's useful, my code is as follows.

```
library(scales)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
chromosomeNAME <- c("chrm1", "chrm1", "chrm2", "chrm2")
geneStart <- c(3714014, 4130851, 264426, 334381)
geneEnd <- c(3735354, 4178170, 307752, 382612)
geneName <- c("geneA", "geneB", "geneC", "geneD")
ChrmLength <- c(6509629, 6509629, 5196352, 5196352)
df <- data.frame(chromosomeNAME, geneStart, geneEnd, geneName, ChrmLength)

chromosomes <- df %>%
  select(chromosomeNAME, ChrmLength) %>%
  unique() %>%
  mutate(ChrmStart = 0)

genes <- df %>%
  select(chromosomeNAME, geneName, geneStart, geneEnd)

ggplot(chromosomes) +
  geom_rect(mapping=aes(xmin=ChrmStart, xmax=ChrmLength, ymin=0, ymax=1), fill="lightblue") +
  geom_rect(genes, mapping=aes(xmin=geneStart, xmax=geneEnd, ymin=0, ymax=1, fill=geneName)) +
  theme_light() +
  theme(axis.title.y=element_blank(),
        axis.text.y=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y=element_blank()) +
  scale_x_continuous(labels = comma) +
  facet_grid(chromosomeNAME~.)
```